# Background speaks to all tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I make a change in my extension, the content script lets the background page know. I would like to then let every other content script know of this change. How do I keep track of or is there a command that will return me the content scripts running my extension?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all tabs in all windows (`chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true})`) and send request to every tab.

Comment: Isn't that pretty inefficient? And what happens when I send a request to a tab that isn't one of my content scripts? Does it just ignore it or is there something special that I have to filter for the content script regex?

Comment: @user592419 If there is no content script in that tab nothing bad would happen. Efficient or not there is no other way I am aware of. Maybe instead of sending data to tabs it would work better if you request the data from background page inside content scripts, when it is needed?

Comment: Each content script needs to see that there was a change. So my choices are to either have a time interval of updating (ask if there are updates, pause for X time, repeat) or to just let each tab know that there is a change.

Comment: @user592419 I would go with looping through all tabs and sending request to each of them.